Flutter Videoplayer not working/initialising
I want to play an video with delay but the videoplayer is not working/initialising. the delay is working but i nether get the init print or the error print of the video player. The current video is shown, so the camera is working and the path to the video is also existing. Is there maybe a problem when the video recording is going on and i want to show the video and how could i solve it, if this is the problem
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  CameraScreen({required this.camera});

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  late CameraController _cameraController;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  late VideoPlayerController? _videoPlayerController;
  String? _currentRecordingPath;
  Duration delay = Duration(seconds: 5);
  bool _isRecording = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cameraController = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
    );
    _initializeControllerFuture = _cameraController.initialize();
    _videoPlayerController = null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    _videoPlayerController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<String> _getTemporaryFilePath() async {
    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    return '${directory.path}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.mp4';
  }

  Future<void> _startRecording() async {
    if (_isRecording) return;

    _currentRecordingPath = await _getTemporaryFilePath();
    await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
    setState(() {
      _isRecording = true;
    });

    // Begin playback with a delay
    _playDelayedVideo();
  }

  Future<void> _stopRecording() async {
    if (!_isRecording) return;

    await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
    setState(() {
      _isRecording = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _playDelayedVideo() async {
    if (_currentRecordingPath == null) {
      print('No recording path set');
      return;
    }

    print('Current recording path: $_currentRecordingPath');
    final file = File(_currentRecordingPath!);
    if (!await file.exists()) {
      print('File does not exist');
      return;
    }

    print('Waiting for delay');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    print('Delay completed');

    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(file)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        print('VideoPlayer initialized');
        setState(() {
          _videoPlayerController!.play();
          _videoPlayerController!.setLooping(true);
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('Error initializing VideoPlayer: $error');
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Camera Screen')),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Delayed video playback in the center
          if (_videoPlayerController != null &&
              _videoPlayerController!.value.isInitialized)
            Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController!.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController!),
              ),
            ),

          // Live camera preview in the top-left corner
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            left: 10,
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            child: FutureBuilder<void>(
              future: _initializeControllerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    child: CameraPreview(_cameraController),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    width: 150,
                    height: 150,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),

          // Controls at the bottom
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record, color: Colors.red),
                  onPressed: _startRecording,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.stop, color: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: _stopRecording,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I just modified your _stopRecording() method.
Now its working my device.
Future<void> _stopRecording() async {
    if (!_isRecording) return;

    XFile? file = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
    await file.saveTo(_currentRecordingPath!);
    // Begin playback with a delay
    _playDelayedVideo();
    setState(() {
      _isRecording = false;
    });
  }

You can even check for the _currentRecordingPath is null or not.
And stop calling _playDelayedVideo in _startRecording() in method
